# Display text on Canvas in Mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Currently, I'm working on Below Example https://codepen.io/jkiss/pen/OVEeqK
here I'm changed the code to display on the canvas

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('nokey');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillText("StacOverFlow",30,80);
```

But I'm not able to display the text by using above code. Could any one please help to display the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your example https://codepen.io/jkiss/pen/OVEeqK , you have to add some code to render function like following:

**live example:**
https://codepen.io/siamand/pen/BdPBMq

```
// Render
function render(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can_w, can_h);

    renderBalls();

    renderLines();

    updateBalls();

    addBallIfy();

    addCustomStuff();


    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function addCustomStuff(){
   //if(mouse_in){  // IF condition for show text when mouse_in
      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
      ctx.fillText("StackOverflow",mouse_ball.x,mouse_ball.y);
   //}
}
```

Comment: its working, but my intention is text should be constant, I mean I want to display on convas, not to display when we move the mouse

Comment: Could please tell me I want to display the text constant

Comment: What do you mean by constant ? if you talk about the text location , just replace x and y with constant values @RamBM

Comment: I mean text has to display even neither nor move the mouse on Canvas.

Comment: Did you got I  mean?

Comment: if you wanna display text constantly on canvas (Like a copyright or watermark) you should remove the IF condition.

Comment: Thanks it did, It helps me lot

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following html code:

``` <canvas id="nokey" width="800" height="800">
    Your Browser Don't Support Canvas, Please Download Chrome ^_^``
</canvas> ```

This is because when you call `var canvas = document.getElementById('nokey');` you are trying to get the canvas named 'nokey' in your example.

Comment: I have added already above mention code it not displaying my content on . see once and let me know

Comment: is the html in a separate file and if so are the js and html files in the same folder?

Comment: oh wait sorry you wont need to worry about that if youre using code pen. But make sure the html is in the html part and the js is in the js section

Comment: take a look at this. I think it is what you want to do:(https://codepen.io/jkiss/pen/OVEeqK)

Comment: your given link not showing text , pleaSE SEE ONCE]

Comment: @deniel , I want to display text with animation effects

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ctx.fillStyle` and `ctx.font` also to display font on canvas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('nokey'),
  can_w = parseInt(canvas.getAttribute('width')),
  can_h = parseInt(canvas.getAttribute('height')),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.font = "bold 16px Arial";
ctx.fillText("StackOverFlow", 30, 80);
```

```html
<canvas id="nokey" width="800" height="800">
    Your Browser Don't Support Canvas, Please Download Chrome ^_^``
</canvas>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/RamBM/pen/eEjOLY see this link. I have changed code. but still it is not showing text